# No missions except questionmarks and Lester at 35% completion

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have completed GTA 5 for 35% just completed the 40th mission. After the online update I didn't see any missions except the question marks and the Lester missions. I already did one Lester mission. Don't want to complete the rest because of the stocks change with this mission. I'm waiting untill I almost completed the game so I can invest more money on the stock changes.

Do I need to complete these Lester missions to really continue? Or is there a bug or something that's preventing me to continue?

This could maybe help to the solution.
One of the last messages I got with Michel:
Collins? needs to receive the JB 700 before anyone gets paid. I googled this, the car looks like to be a James Bond car or something. I have never seen this car in the game. Do I need to steal this somewhere so I can deliver it and continue with the story line?

Comment: It is a bug... when shutting down your ps3 with power switch i believe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. The developers are currently working on a fix.
I solved this issue by loading an older save game and restart from that point. If you don't have an older save game you can wait until the release of this fix. Don't think this fix will be published soon because of all the issues with GTA online. Or you always can start over...

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the next Mission which is assigned by Devin. Look on [this site](http://www.supercheats.com/gta5/walkthrough/main-mission-42-deep-inside) to read more.

The video will also explain where to go to get the vehicle and shows you what to do.

Comment: Seems indeed to be the mission. Going to try it tomorrow. Weird I don't have a D on the map... Lets hope it works!

Comment: @Freddy If this is the answer you were looking for why don't you hit the grey check mark and up-vote it for future visitors.

Comment: No need to explain me how this works. Let me try the solution before I mark it as an answer. I can't upvote answers with 1 point of reputation....

Comment: Its apparently a bug after the online update. I went to the spot of this mission you posted. Couldn't start the mission...

Comment: @Freddy Thanks for that. I'm past that so didn't know it was a bug.