# Why aren't any main story missions showing up anymore?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After doing the "Surveying the score" mission on GTA5 it appears that I cannot progress any farther into the story. No markers for main missions are on the map for any character, but I still have access to things like Strangers and Freaks, street races and such.

**EDIT**
So it has been a long time since this happened and I still am not sure if this got some kinda fix or not? I tried playing GTA5 again after not playing it for a very long time because this glitch annoyed me so much, downloaded three patches, and  have noticed nothing. Should I just give up on this save file at this point?

Comment: potentially related question; http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133148/no-missions-except-questionmarks-and-lester-at-35-completion There do appear to be some bugs that halt mission progression.

Comment: From your description, I am assuming you can still access all 3 characters? Seems lots of people are experiencing a variation of this bug; some can't switch to Michael, but can see a blue M on their map, some have no main mission markers but can switch between all. One solution involves calling a cab, then using it to quick travel to the M whilst playing as Franklin. Unfortunately, it seems you don't have the M to be able to try this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete 3 missions of Strangers in order to unlock the next main mission. The next mission is called [Stingers.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Stingers)

If you have done more than three then you are experiencing a bug that other people are experiencing.

Comment: Ive done more than three and nothing has happend

Comment: Interestingly, if you go to the walkthrough for "Surveying the score" on that site, the comments show several other people stuck after that mission.

Comment: I completed the main story with started only 1 strangers missions...

Answer (score 0):

**Could you delete the game data (not saves) and re install?**

I would say this should be a last resort, but I believe it should fix it if there are no other possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Some missions are activated by phone. try checking you contacts on all characters. if it didn't work you might want to try saving your game into another slot using "quick save" and reloading new save. 
Alternatively, in some cases, taking a cab ride, and then choosing the “skip” option, which forces a load screen has been known to resolve some progression blocks.

also [Rockstargames](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200506327-What-to-do-if-no-further-missions-are-showing-up-in-GTAV-Story-Mode) support said that taking a cab ride, and then "skipping"  which forces a load screen and fix bug.

otherwise it means that your game file is corrupted. it might happen because of rare occasions when applying a Title Update. and if you think that Title Update might be a reason you should Reload saved file before Update.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you need to complete flight school or schooting range before you can do a mission.

Comment: I have not done flight school OR shooting range. I guess I will try that out when I get a chance.

Comment: Neither of those helped. Looks like I really am screwed at this point.

Comment: you need to do flight school with michal and schooting range with franklin and when you did those you will get a call. at least thats how it worked for me.

Comment: I actually did it that way....do i have to do the Whole flight school?

Comment: I did most of it, not everything.

Comment: Lame....waiting for a patch then i suppose