# I think I am stuck, is there a way to trigger a mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have been playing GTA V for a few hours now without any mission starting. I have just stolen the helicopter from the base, took flight school but now nothing is happening.

Is there a way to trigger the next story mode mission?

*or*

- Do I need all Gold in the flight school?
- I see a 'B' on my radar, but when I get there nothing happens, its just a building with a big garage in the ground floor. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you try to walk really close to that building? I mean, really really close?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133813 or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133148

Comment: What colour is the 'B'? Maybe you need a different character to trigger it. Blue=Michael, Green=Franklin, Orange=Trevor.

Comment: ^^ This.  I guess that's Barry, who starts off as a strangers and freaks side-mission, but you can play it as all 3.  With Franklin there are a few missions to complete, where Michael and Trevor only have 1 each (and bizarre ones they are too!)  Try going to the B as Franklin and see if that triggers anything.  It sounds buggy to me, as I don't remember and strangers and freaks missions being *required* to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the button you use to swap character `Alt` on PC.

Look for the number in front of Trevor, Michael and Franklin. If there is none it is because there is no mission left for that char. Swap for one who does because he is the one who will trigger that mission (the color is a hint too).

That number means the quantity of missions available for the char.

If the mission do not start when you reach the place, look for a yellow spot on the ground, or to enter some doors - I got I graphics bug with the last nvidia driver that make those disappear, as well as the circles on the stun plane. =(

Answer (score 1):

Swap to Trevor and go to the apartment he is staying in

Comment: Could you develop your answer a bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

That building is (if I am correct) underneath a road. To begin the mission you need to go **above** the road, and the mission will be triggered. I got stuck in exactly the same way before.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar spot. I had to run the ? mission, which was the first towing mission for Tonya. That triggered two main story missions for me.