# Why are there no main missions appearing in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm playing on the ps3 version of GTA V. I've gotten up to the '*Minisub*' mission, where you have to steal the mini-sub with Trevor. This was after the '*Scouting the Port*' mission where you investigate and take pictures of the cargo ship that Merryweather is protecting - but that's the only story mission that would show up.

I played a bunch of strangers and freaks missions that had appeared and nothing else happened I thought that I needed to complete the flight training but that just didn't lead to anything. I waited for moments of in-game time and still nothing. I am playing on the latest version of the game for the ps3 version.

I have completed all of the side missions that were available.

I have checked the character wheel to see if a mission number was there and checked the map with all characters for blips.

I have checked another question that looked similar to my question but when I tried a taxi trick it didn't work and someone had already suggested I try that. another trick that was mentioned on the other question was that I should try flight school with Michael and that's what I mentioned earlier. it also said to go to Ammunation firing range with Franklin but I went there and did some of those with him and still nothing. I have gotten Michael to 100 on flying and franklin to 100 on shooting.

Why aren't any main missions appearing?

Comment: Related questions: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133813/143571 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133161/143571 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136372/143571

Comment: i checked these that's what i was talking about when I said I checked another question. i tried these and still no change

Answer (score -1):

but one thing you can try is to copy your save then delete the old one and try the new one or try to fast travel in a taxi.

Comment: im sorry but none of these worked.